# How to calculate the average from a list of data contained in an html link

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the average $ value from the data contained in the below link: [data](https://s3.amazonaws.com/mikeghen/costs_2012.txt)

I'm able to import the data into python with the code listed below but I'm having trouble figuring out how to either sum all the values and divide by the total number of values or if there is a average command within the python library?

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/mikeghen/costs_2012.txt") as response:
    html = response.read().decode().split()
    print(html[0:10])
```

When I run the module I get this so that I know I was able to successfully import the data from the html link to python:

```
['$19,056.91', '$1,824.85', '$455.89', '$122,107.43', '$342.18', '$1,714.61', '$11,745.65', '$1,575.86', '$1,724.06', '$32,888.16']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have all the prices in your list. You need to remove the "$" sign from them, remove "," from them and convert them to float since its in str by default. Then you can use the sum function to sum all the values and then simply divide by the length of the list

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://s3.amazonaws.com/mikeghen/costs_2012.txt") as response:
    html = response.read().decode().split()
    html = [float(x[1:].replace(',', '')) for x in html]
    print(sum(html)/len(html))
    print(html[1:10])
```